# Why are negative option prices possible for callable US treasury bonds?

Tags: options, option-pricing, treasuries, callable-bonds

I am not familiar enough with the theories of option pricing to understand how negative option prices are possible. I found two research papers indicating that negative option prices are indeed possible for callable US treasury bonds:

- [Are Negative Option Prices Possible? The Callable U.S. Treasury-Bond Puzzle](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2353198)
- [Negative option values are possible: The impact of Treasury bond futures on the cash U.S. Treasury market](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X97000251)

Can someone explain why negative option prices are possible for callable US treasury bonds?

Comment: Interesting. But FWIW all USTR bonds nowadays are not callable.

Comment: An actual option with an independent existence cannot have a negative price. But we are talking here about 'embedded options' that are part of another security (in this case a USTR bond) and cannot be separated from their parent. Their price is not quoted in the marketplace but is found by a calculation. The problem is that this calculation comes up with a negative number. It is more an ANOMALY IN BOND PRICING than a fact about options. The bond pricing takes other considerations into account that completely overwhelm the embedded optionality and make the calculation come out the way it does.

Comment: It shows the Embedded Option approach to security valuation does not always work.Because there could be another component of price which we have forgotten to include.

Comment: @noob2 Your comments are helpful. Please copy them into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An actual option with an independent existence cannot have a negative price. But we are talking here about 'embedded options' that are part of another security (in this case a USTR bond) and cannot be separated from their parent. Their price is not quoted in the marketplace but is found by a calculation. The problem is that this calculation comes up with a negative number. It is more an ANOMALY IN BOND PRICING than a fact about options. The bond pricing takes other considerations into account that completely overwhelm the embedded optionality and make the calculation come out the way it does.

It shows the Embedded Option approach to security valuation does not always work. Because there could be another component of price which we have forgotten to include (an omitted component).